# Перетаскивание двух форм c#

Tags: c#

Как сделать перетаскивание форм как в **WinAmp'e**?

Windows Forms

Описываю...

В винампе есть функция, как перемещение главной формы вместе с рядом находящейся формы эквалайзера.

Желательный эффект - при расположении "соприсокносновения" форм, то формы как одно целое (перемещаются при перемещении главной формы) , а при отнесённом окне эквалайзера, оно как отдельное, независимое окно...

Comment: вы чего хотите? чтобы все, кто может ответить, пошли смотреть как некие формы перетаскиваются в WinAmp? задавая вопрос, не ленитесь правильно объяснять задачу, хотя бы...

Comment: @VasyaLi в 2014 году далеко не все продолжают пользоваться этим замечательным плеером, а потому словосочетание "перетаскивание как в WinAmp'e" вряд ли будет понятно каждому

Comment: @DreamChild К сожалению поддержка уже прикрыта (
а в 2004 лучше вроде и не было...

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужен некий контрол - контейнер и события [DoDragDrop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.dodragdrop(v=vs.110).aspx) от дочерних контролов.

Comment: А можно немного по подробнее, или пример, если можно...